# Detecting System Architecture in Ant

Tags: ant

Is there a way to find what architecture an ant script is running on? Currently I have the following:

```
<echo>System = ${os.name} ${os.arch}</echo>
```

which produces:

```
[echo] System = Linux i386
```

This not correct, as I am running 64 bit linux.

Thank you

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218989/how-to-determine-build-architecture-32bit-64bit-with-ant/219081

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Ant is running inside a JVM, it will only detect the architecture of the JVM. Run Ant with a 64-bit JVM and you'll get a different value of ${os.arch}.

If you want to detect the architecture of the underlying OS, you need to look at environment variables or check the output from something like `uname`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe Java's system property ${os.arch}. More information [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#built-in-props).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
<property environment="env"/>
<condition property="systemWindows" value="64" else="86">
   <available file="${env.windir}/SysWOW64"/>
</condition>
```